# Keep the screen turned on using a floating widget service in android

Tags: android, service, widget, flags, floating

I'am new to android development. I have method to keep the screen on using a switch control in a floating widget.

```
    public void onSwitchClick(View view) {
    aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           if (isChecked) { // The switch is enabled
               //int flag = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
               //mLayoutParams.flags=flag;
               //mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingWidgetView.getRootView(), mLayoutParams);
               //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ON",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           } else { // The switch is disabled
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OFF",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   });
}
```

When the user clicks on the switch it should keep the screen on. I have gone through many answers about WakeLock, Flags but non of the solutions worked for me. Application crashed when I press turn the switch on. Note that this method is in a service and Toast messages works fine. Your help is highly appreciated.

Following code segment do not provide any compilation errors but does not work in run time.

```
int flag = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
mLayoutParams.flags=flag;
mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingWidgetView.getRootView(), mLayoutParams);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use the `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` in an Activity that will only be on the screen sometimes. Instead you need to use a `WakeLock` to keep the screen on at full or partial brightness.

First you'll need to declare the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Then you'll need to acquire a `WakeLock` using the `PowerManager` and make sure you **release** it. Release the `WakeLock` means you won't needlessly kill the user's battery.

```
WakeLock mScreenWakeLock = null;

PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
mScreenWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK,
    "widget-screen-wakelock");

// You only want one WakeLock to deal with.
mScreenWakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);

// Grab the WakeLock and make sure the screen stays on 
mScreenWakeLock.acquire();
```

Then when you don't need it anymore you can release it:

```
mScreenWakeLock.release()
```

Note that you might want to add a limit to the amount of time that you can hold a `WakeLock` so you don't hold it forever, especially since you are creating a floating widget. You can do that by passing a maximum number of milliseconds to the acquire method:

```
// Hold WakeLock for upto 1 hour.
mScreenWakeLock.acquire(3600000);
```

And you can see what `WakeLocks` are in use by your application using `adb`:

```
adb shell dumpsys power | grep -i "package.name"
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. You saved the day. But SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated sinnce API 13, The recommendation is to use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON instead. If I can't use this on a service then is there any other way to do this?

Comment: They recommend using the flag only with Activities because they are only sometimes on the screen so you don't risk wasting the user's battery when they are not using your app, so it is fool proof. Unfortunately that's not your use case. You want the screen on even when they are not looking at your app so you have to use WakeLocks directly.